# How do I change a constant value to a column header in SQL?

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

The SQL query:

```
select type,count(*), 'Active'                            
   from file where removed = '0'                                
union all 
select type,count(*), 'Removed' 
   from file where removed = '1'
```

gives:

```
 TYPE                     COUNT ( * )   Constant value  
  A                         24,168      Active       
  A                              1      Removed      
  B                          8,280      Active       
  B                          1,263      Removed
```

However, how can I change the SQL to get:

```
TYPE                     Active  Removed   
A                         24,168    1       
B                          8,280  1,263
```

Supplementary optional question: and what's the best way to include the following total?

```
TYPE                     Active  Removed   
A                         24,168      1       
B                          8,280  1,263  
Total                     32,448  1,264
```

This is my best answer to the supplementary, please let me know if you see any flaws or improvements:

```
select 
    type, 
    sum(CASE WHEN removed = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Active',
    sum(CASE WHEN removed = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Removed'                            

from file                                
Group by type

union all

select 'Total',
sum(CASE WHEN removed = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Active',
sum(CASE WHEN removed = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Removed'                            

from file
```

Thank you to everyone who commented or answered, your help is appreciated.

Comment: You have to use `join` not `Union`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
select 
    type, 
    sum(CASE WHEN removed = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Active',
    sum(CASE WHEN removed = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Removed'                            
from file                                
Group by type
```

Comment: This query will return the results that you are looking for.

Comment: @Jake - Great suggestion, exactly what I was looking for, just needed to drop the single quotes around 'Active' and 'Removed'. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `case` expressions to do conditional aggregation:

```
select type,
       count(case when removed = '0' then 1 end) as "Active",                            
       count(case when removed = '1' then 1 end) as "Removed"                           
from file                       
group by type
```

If there are many rows with other removed values than 0/1, and the column is indexed, you can throw in a

```
WHERE removed IN ('0','1')
```

to speed things up!

Comment: I think you need to edit your `where` clause.  Won't the top query only get `removed = 0` counts and not `removed = 1`?

Comment: Won't your WHERE clause here filter out some wanted results?

Comment: @Jake, sorry, now I see... copy-and-paste error... Thanks!

Comment: @WEI_DBA, now I see... copy-and-paste error... Thanks!

Comment: Thanks guys, nice solution, was easily able to extend it to add a total column too.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get totals into the answer without `union` try:

```
select 
  coalesce(type, 'Totals') type,
  sum(CASE WHEN removed = '0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Active,
  sum(CASE WHEN removed = '1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) Removed
from file                                
Group by rollup(type)
```

This works for v6.1 and later.

Comment: A much more elegant solution, many thanks @jmarkmurphy. Just edited to add a missing comma.